# passing parameter value through pgoledb to postgresql stored function

Tags: postgresql, vbscript, asp-classic, adodb

I am attempting to migrate a legacy client-server GIS application from Microsoft SQL Server to PostgreSQL.  In this system the SQL Server database contains a large set of `T-SQL` stored procedures, each being an SQL Select query with one or more parameters.

In response to a client request, the server program – `classic ASP VBScript` – uses `Microsoft ADODB` to fill in the parameters values, execute the requested query and return the result set as an XML document to the client.

In the preliminary phase of the migration I have successfully:

1. installed `PostgreSQL 9.3` for Windows, `PgOleDB 1.0.0.20` and `psqlODBC` on a `32.bit` Windows 7 Pro development PC
2. migrated the SQL Server database table definitions and constraint to a new `PostgreSQL` database and populated the tables using psqlODBC
3. using pgAdmin III, created and executed test queries against the PostgreSQL database
4. using pgAdmin III, created two test PostgreSQL table-valued Select functions – test1() one with no parameters and test2(text) with a single IN parameter  — and verified that both execute correctly
5. written a test ASP/VBscript program that uses `ADODB.Connection` and `ADODB.Command` to connect to the PostgreSQL database, execute test1() - the no-parameter stored function - and create an `ADODB.Recordset`.  This test works  correctly.

However when I change my test ASP/VBscript program to use `test2()` and use `objCmd.Parameters.Append` like this:

```
objCmd.CommandText = "test2"

objCmd.Parameters.Append objCmd.CreateParameter("p1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 15, "000007-01012013")
```

to specify the required IN parameter,  I get the ASP  runtime error:

```
PgOleDB error '80004005'   “Procedure name for automatic arguments is not unique“
```

Q1. What does the diagnostic “Procedure name for automatic arguments is not unique” mean?

Q2. Is there any public documentation available for PgOleDB other than the `README.TXT` and `RELEASENOTES.TXT` files installed along with `PgOleDB.dll`?

Comment: In `psql` run `\df test2`. You'll probably see two or more results, as I suspect you've overloaded `test2`'s name with multiple versions.